# Javascript Execution Problems in a Single Page Webapp

Tags: web, web-applications, single-page-application

I've been trying to design a single page webapp (a game) that will load different HTML documents dynamically into a single webpage.

I'm using pure Javascript (no libraries) and have used XMLhttprequest to download HTML files and display them on-the-fly on a single webpage. This all works great except for the Javascript.

As my Javascript has no way of knowing which dynamic document is loaded at any one time all my scripts are trying to run and it's causing a great deal of errors where scripts are trying to access elements that are not there on the page.

I need to be able to download and run Javascript files on the fly or I need to be able to detect which HTML document I am displaying and activate only the relevant Javascript code.

Does anyone know a solution to my problem or has any better ideas?

Thanks
Barry

Comment: Why do people mark down the people asking the questions? It so annoying. I'm just trying to get some help and I'm just trying to explain the situation the best I can

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand your question, you wanted to dynamically load everything depending on certain scenario,
first in rendering HTML, I will recommend you to use MVC and observer pattern,
second to dynamically load the script, you wanted

scene 1 :
myScripts.load(['script1', 'script2'])

scene 2 :
myScripts.load(['script2','script3'])

scene 3 :
myScripts.load(['script1'])

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I've managed to workout how to do it myself. I've updated the stackoverflow page with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to write the solution myself thanks.

**Description of the solution.**

1. It loads a JSON file. In the JSON file is a list of objects representing my website. Each JSON webpage has a single HTML webpage address and a list of all the JavaScript files I want loaded. Please note some objects in this file are for future use for my program.
2. It then gets the first webpage using data in the JSON file using XMLhttpRequest and places the contents into the index.html page.
3. Under load_javascript(x) function it first trys to remove any previously dynamically added JavaScript files by looking for the data-jsloader attribute. This is a custom attribute that my program attaches to any dynamically added JavaScript so it can be found and removed when the user changes webpages in my program.
4. In the same function (load_javascript) the program will then go through the list of JavaScript files needed to be added dynamically to the current page and then  it will attached the data-jsloader to it.

**Why I have done this.**

I'm writing a multi-threaded, multi-player Facebook poker game that uses web sockets to talk to a Node back-end server. I have multiple webpages in this game that all needed to be connected via web sockets to my back-end Node server. Every time the user navigated between webpages the WebSocket connection would be reset and the webpage would have to reconnect to the server.

I thought a better solution would be to have one webpage and one JavaScript file that would connect to the node back-end server using web sockets, I would just change the content of that webpage keeping the WebSocket connection alive even if the game changed websites. So far it has worked

**Javascript File**

```
let website_data;

(function() {

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", "/json/mysites.json");

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
        {       
            website_data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            load_webpage(0);
        }
    }

    request.send();
})()


function load_webpage(x)
{
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;   
                load_javascript(x);           
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", website_data[x].html_address);
    location.hash = website_data[x].hash;

    xhttp.send();    
}


function load_javascript(x)
{
    let element;

    // gets a list of all 
    let scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

    let t = scripts.length;
    while (t--)
    {
        if(scripts[t].hasAttribute('data-jsloader') && scripts[t].getAttribute('data-jsloader') != x)
        {
            console.log(scripts[t].getAttribute('data-jsloader')); 
            scripts[t].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[t]);
        }
    }

    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("script"));

    // load javascript files
    for(let i = 0; i < website_data[x].js_script.length; i++)
    {
        // console.log("Adding Javacscript File: " + website_data[x].js_script[i]);
        element = document.createElement('script');
        element.setAttribute("data-jsloader", x.toString());
        element.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        element.setAttribute("src", website_data[x].js_script[i]);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

**JSON File (Contains lists of websites and associated JS file locations)**

```
[
{
    "page_number":0,
    "html_address":"/views/splashpage.html",
    "hash": "splashpage.html",
    "js_script":["/js/background.js","/js/splashpage.js"]
},
{
    "page_number":1,
    "html_address":"/views/menu.html",
    "hash": "menu.html",
    "js_script":["/js/menu.js"]
},
{
    "page_number":2,
    "html_address":"/views/lobby.html",
    "hash": "lobby.html",
    "js_script":["/js/lobby.js"]
},
{   
    "page_number":3,        
    "html_address":"/views/kingpin.html",
    "hash": "game.html",
    "js_script":["/js/cards.js", 
                 "/js/chat.js", 
                 "/js/chips.js", 
                 "/js/ws_client.js", 
                 "/js/betting_controls.js", 
                 "/js/kingpin.js",
                 "/js/footer.js", 
                 "/js/ads_and_purchases.js"] 
    }
]
```

**Index.html (Where the webpage content is loaded)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Kingpin</title>

    <!-- index css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>


</body>
</html>
```